# VS Code GLFW and GLAD development in Mac and Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, glfw, glad

I just wanted to ask if anyone has been able to setup your GLFW/GLAD project in VS Code to work both in Mac and Windows, as I usually have to switch between those 2 OS and I would like to be able to work on my project on both of them.

Answer (score 0):

These libraries work across multiple platforms, and program code that uses them can too. Building your projects is your primary issue, which you can do either by writing a build script for both of your platforms, a makefile, or by using something like MSYS2/Cygwin to make your Windows environment more like your Mac one. I'm sure there are many other options too!

You'll want to set up version control to allow you to work on the same project from both environments without having to copy files over manually. Unless you want to compile all our libraries from source (which you might), your best bet would be to ignore your library folders from the main version control branch so that they can differ between environments.